# Factoring trinomial with variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

$$7y^{2a+b}-5y^{a+b}+3y^{a+2b}$$

I don't really kow how to start...I guess a $y$ could be factored out but that's completely useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
7y^{2a+b}-5y^{a+b}+3y^{a+2b}=y^{a+b}(7y^a-5+3y^b)
$$

Comment: Wait...that's it?

Comment: I think so! It is a factorisation isn't it?

Comment: Yes, thanks! Surprised it turned out to be so simple